# Macbook Air SSD overheating

Tags: ssd, macbook

I have installed Ubuntu on my Macbook air. 
Everything is fine, but the SSD reach aroud 70°C. Yet on Yosemite the SSD is around 40-50°C.

What is wrong ?

(Macbook air early 2014, 6.2)

Comment: Anyone ? 
I really dont understand why my SSD is burning.

Comment: Anyone ? I really dont understand why my SSD is burning.

Comment: any updates on your situation? has any answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to different factors.

1. The graphic driver you use, might impact the power consumption and thus the temperature.
2. If you are using a long term support (LTS) version of ubuntu, you are less likely to be running inappropriate drivers simultaneously.
3. As a precaution, given your situation, please avoid running the macbook air with lid closed (e.g. when connected to an external monitor) until you resolve this.

Have you tried installing the mac fan control daemon?

```
sudo apt-get install macfanctld
```

This helps controlling many performance issues interrelated to the CPU, fan, Temp.

Answer (score 0):

I run Ubuntu on an iMac and MacBoook. On my iMac I've had to manually control the fan rate because a faulty read from the internal temperature sensor. I'd recommend seeing what temperature readings you're getting and consider manually setting the fan rate.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons why that might be happening, try running `iotop` that'll give you an idea what's taking a dole on your SSD and quite frankly MAC dosen't have a very good history of playing well with anything other than OSX.

Answer (score 0):

When an SSD gets too hot it slows itself down. When you first boot your laptop run a speed test:

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/nvme0n1p5

/dev/nvme0n1p5:
 Timing cached reads:   16410 MB in  1.99 seconds = 8228.22 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 6190 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2063.30 MB/sec
```

When you see it hit 70 degrees rerun the test. If the speed is reduced it confirms the drive is getting hot. If the speed is consistent it could be a faulty temperature report.